# What is the best tool to create videos like that

Tags: video, animation

I want to create animation videos very similar to the following videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VW6cc8fqQVo
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWiC6SqTBoc

From your experience, What are the best tools to learn to do that?

Thanks,
Yasser

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what you want. Add screenshots if necessary. Questions on SE sites should be self contained and we should not have to go elsewhere to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest taking a look at [krita](https://krita.org/) which has the following points in its favor:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source *(there are also paid options with automatic updates)*
- Windows 7/10, Windows Portable, OS-X & Linux
- Supportive community including the developers
- Multiple Languages supported
- Pressure Sensitive Tablet Support
- [Animation](https://krita.org/en/animate-with-krita/) tools since version 3.0
- Layers
- Timeline
- Controllable Onion Skinning
- [Animation Rendering](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/render_animation.html#render-animation) (since 3.1) usint FFMPEG
- [More animation features](https://community.kde.org/Krita/Docs/AnimationGuiFeaturesList)
- For some tutorials and examples see [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=krita%20animation)
- See [this](https://www.deviantart.com/popular-all-time/?section=&global=1&q=krita&offset=0) Deviant Art search for some examples of Krita work

### The 2019 Mascot

[image]

### The vision statement

> Krita is a free and open source cross-platform application that offers
>   an end-to-end solution for creating digital art files from scratch.
>   Krita is optimized for frequent, prolonged and focused use. Explicitly
>   supported fields of painting are illustrations, concept art, matte
>   painting, textures, comics and animations. Developed together with
>   users, Krita is an application that supports their actual needs and
>   workflow. Krita supports open standards and interoperates with other
>   applications.